How to create a relative Symlink whilst mounted?
I recently bricked my system due to checkinstall. It seems all that is missing is my lib folder.
However I have tried to create a symlink whilst the system is mounted and I get the following symlink: lib -> /mnt/root/usr/lib/ The issue I can see with this is when I have not mounted the system at /mnt/root this link does not exist... How can I create it to point to /usr/lib, of course doing sudo ln -s /usr/lib /lib will just create a link for the current system.
Current structure
(base) hutber@hutber:/mnt/root$ ll
total 116
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root  4096 Nov 28 09:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Nov 28 09:10 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Aug 12 13:14 1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Feb  2  2024 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 21 11:44 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 cdrom/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 12 13:15 .config/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jan  9  2024 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 164 root root 12288 Nov 27 22:56 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    17 Nov 28 09:25 lib -> /mnt/root/usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Jan  9  2024 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Feb  2  2024 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 media/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Feb 14  2024 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root  4096 Sep 19 13:30 opt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  9  2024 proc/
drwx------  13 root root  4096 Oct  8 13:00 root/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Feb  2  2024 run/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Feb  2  2024 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  9  2024 srv/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 18  2022 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  49 root root 20480 Nov 27 23:01 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Apr 11  2024 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Feb 14  2024 var/


https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/780268/70524 ... "doing sudo ln -s /usr/lib /lib will just create a link for the current system" ... while you're in the live system, yes, but boot back into the installed system and then /usr/lib will be in the installed system.

lib should be set up exactly as the other symlinks in root directory that are visible on the listing you posted, like bin or lib64 - ie. it should point to usr/lib (important: not /usr/lib, but usr/lib, because the latter is relative to the point where this filesystem is mounted - if it's mounted at actual root, the link will point to /usr/lib, but if this filesystem will be mounted at /mnt/root, the link will point to /mnt/root/usr/lib).
So while in the directory /mnt/root, type
sudo ln -s -f usr/lib lib

(the -f parameter forces replacement of current link with the new one).
